# how to disable security component for certain actions in cakephp?

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I have a form in my `add_note` action, where I do not want `SecurityComponent` to put its tokens or checking. How do I do this?

I have tried `requireAuth('some_other_action')` etc. but it doesn't work.

Comment: Just a reference, it's possible to unlock individual fields from within the view file. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36317882/722036).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original answer for CakePHP 1.2 to 2.2.x:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (isset($this->Security) && $this->action == 'add_note') {
        $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    }
}
```

---

Updated answer for CakePHP 2.3+ and 3.x (as pointed out in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165751/how-to-disable-security-component-for-certain-actions-in-cakephp/21932588#21932588)):

```
public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
     $this->Security->config('unlockedActions', ['add_note']);
}
```

---

Also, it's possible to unlock specific fields (as pointed out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165751/how-to-disable-security-component-for-certain-actions-in-cakephp#comment60326202_7165751))

```
$this->Form->unlockField('Note.id');
```

Comment: Does $this->Form->unlockField('Note.id'); work in CakePHP 1.2?

Comment: For CakePHP 1.2, have a look at `SecurityComponent::$disabledFields`. `FormHelper::unlockField()` wasn't added until CakePHP 2.0.

Answer (score 5):

In CakePhp 2.3 do:

```
$this->Security->unlockedActions= array('add_note');
```