# How to 'unlock' a field in a CakePHP form when it is part of a hasMany association

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-many

I have a form that represents a `RewardModifier` table in our database. That `RewardModifier` `hasMany` `RewardOption`.

My form is structured like this (image):

[image]

So, the `RewardModifier` can have many elements on the page, each with many `RewardOption` items.

**The Problem**

The problem is, that users can delete sections of this form using Javascript, which essentially removes it from the DOM. When they do that, it breaks the security component, because the POST'ed fields do not match the token supplied when the page was generated.

Now, I have been using `unlockedFields` to handle this before:

```
$this->Security->disabledFields = array(
   'PrjRewardModifier.reward_id',
   'PrjRewardModifier.title',
   'PrjRewardModifier.option_type',
   'PrjRewardOption.description',
   'PrjRewardOption.modifier',
   'PrjRewardOption.amount'
);
```

I know that `disabledFields` is deprecated, but we are using that for the time being.

When I debug the posted form data in the `SecurityComponent`, I see the following:

```
(int) 8 => 'PrjRewardModifier.0.reward_id',
(int) 9 => 'PrjRewardModifier.0.title',
(int) 10 => 'PrjRewardModifier.0.option_type',
(int) 11 => 'PrjRewardModifier.0.PrjRewardOption.0.description',
(int) 12 => 'PrjRewardModifier.0.PrjRewardOption.0.modifier',
(int) 13 => 'PrjRewardModifier.0.PrjRewardOption.0.amount'
```

I need to know how to edit the data being passed to `unlockedFields` so that it can disregard these fields that are keyed for hasMany relationships.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I found adding (the equivalent of) this to the RewardModifier controller did the trick:

```
public function beforeFilter(){
     $this->Security->unlockedFields = array('RewardOption');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me get to the solution :)

Comment: @BarryChapman, could you please post what is the final solution, cause the answer did not work for me. Thanks

Comment: @Barry Chapman Saying that it "helped me get to the solution" doesn't constitute a correct answer unless you specify what that solution actually was.

Comment: Crikey, what was the solution? I'm running into the same problem.

Comment: As of cakePHP 3.x this would be:  
 `$this->Security->config('unlockedFields', ['reward_options']);`  
May be obvious to others, but calling config() threw me for a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following to the form code worked for me

```
$this->Form->unlockField('User.id');
```

Unlocking the fields from within the view files also helps declutter the controller's `beforeFilter()`.

Source: [/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::unlockField](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::unlockField)