# CakePHP security component + hasMany association?

Tags: cakephp

In the CakePHP security component, is there a good way to unlock fields that are part of a hasMany association? I know I can do this in the view:

`$this->Form->unlockField('SomeModel.0.some_field');`

and repeat for 1, 2, etc. but if the user can add an arbitrary number of fields with JavaScript then I won't know how many to unlock.

Is there a way to unlock `SomeModel.*.some_field` without completely disabling post validation on this action?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938555/how-to-unlock-a-field-in-a-cakephp-form-when-it-is-part-of-a-hasmany-associati

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938555/how-to-unlock-a-field-in-a-cakephp-form-when-it-is-part-of-a-hasmany-associati